# Gradle error from an open source code

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle

I tried to reuse and existing code form github :

https://github.com/demantz/RFAnalyzer

I'm opening it with Android Studio and import the project (as it's said on the git page). I'm eperiencing some troubles with gradle which I'm not familiar with.

At first Android Studio tells me that the gradle version used in the the project must be upgraded :

1.12 -> 1.3.

And then I have a message saying that "gradle dsl method not found 'jcenter()'"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JCenter (`jcenter()`) [was introduced by Gradle 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25137263/6309).
See [Gradle 1.7 JCenter repository support](https://docs.gradle.org/1.7/release-notes#jcenter-repository-support).

Make sure to upgrade your Gradle to at least 1.7.
See "[how to check the gradle version in my Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25260172/6309)"

```
File->Project Structure->Project pane->"Android plugin version".
```

> Make sure you don't confuse the Gradle version with the Android plugin version.
>   The former is the build system itself, the latter is the plugin to the build system that knows how to build Android projects

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. it's not working My current Android Plugin Version is 2.4.0. Here's the error message:                                Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.4.0/gradle-2.4.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.4.0/gradle-2.4.0.jar
Required by:
    :RFAnalyzer:unspecified

Comment: @Kruncho would http://stackoverflow.com/a/30967489/6309 (or http://stackoverflow.com/a/31372896/6309) help? Also https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html